# Auth for 2 different tables - Cakephp 3.X

Tags: cakephp-3.0, user-roles

I have table **users** (for admin) & **players** (front-end users). I have successfully implemented `Auth` for admin.

Now I want to implement same for players. I cannot merge users and players table since both have different foreign keys and many tables are dependent on them.

Also, Player registration is done from a different form with many more fields then Admin.

Can anybody please help me?

I started using **CakePHP 3.X**

Comment: Thanks Nadeem for correction.